# want to gettext from span

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to get text "Entered code is already exists" using selenium webdriver , I tried using id="code_error" but no use

HTML code is as follows :

```
<div class="leftsection">
            <div class="form-element">
                <fieldset>
                    <label><span class="required">*</span>Code:</label>
       <input type="text" maxlength="6" value="" id="code" name="code" style="border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);">
               </fieldset>
                  <span role="alert" class="errormsg" id="code_error">Entered Code already exists</span>
            </div>
```

i used xpath , id, cssselecor but it returns NULL.

Comment: Please post sufficient code and data to allow your problem to be reproduced.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the below code..works perfectly

```
options=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("errormsg")
for i in options:
    print i.text
```

Answer (score 0):

when selenium can parse JavaScript, you can use this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('sbucode_error').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Selenium Ide to check whether id=code_error selector pointing to your element then use the below mentioned code to get text from that.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("code_error")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

String text = driver.findElementById("code_error").getText(); should do the trick for you :)